# VBA Code To Use The Password From Another Sub in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection, worksheet

I have two codes, one that protects all sheets which uses the password from an input box, and the second one that deletes `#REF!` errors. On the second code I need to unprotect the sheet first in order to delete a row. Now, I am trying to figure out how can I use the pasword from the first code to unprotect the sheet so that the second code can delete the `#REF!` error rows?

Not sure if is even possible, but maybe someone has had the same problem before.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    Dim pwd1 As String, pwd2 As String
    pwd1 = InputBox("Enter your password", "")
    If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    pwd2 = InputBox("Enter the password again", "")

    If pwd2 = "" Then Exit Sub

     'Checks if both the passwords are identical
    If InStr(1, pwd2, pwd1, 0) = 0 Or _
       InStr(1, pwd1, pwd2, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please type the same password. ", vbInformation, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.ProtectContents = False = True Then
            ws.Protect Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
                True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, Password:=pwd1
        End If

    Next ws

    MsgBox "Sheets are protected."
End Sub



Sub DeleteRows() ' Cells which contain an Error Formula
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect pwd1

    Dim c As Long
    For c = 400 To 2 Step -1
        If IsError(Cells(c, 3)) Then
            Rows(c).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next c
    ws.Protect Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, Password:=pwd1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to declare the variable as `Public`.

```
Public pwd1 As String

Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    'NO dim for pwd1 here
    pwd1 = InputBox("Enter your password", "")
    'your code here
End Sub
```

So it is available in all your procedures and functions.

---

**But I recommend to use `.Protect UserInterFaceOnly:=True`**
 which protects the worksheet from user editing but lets VBA edit it without restrictions.

Therefore you just need to protect your sheets in the `Workbook_Open()` event like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    'Repeat with the name and password of additional sheets to be manipulated by VBA.
End Sub
```

This way you don't need to protect/unprotect for every VBA action.

For a full how-to and more information see: [Speedup Excel VBA Macros with Protect UserInterFaceOnly](http://www.criticaltosuccess.com/speedup-excel-vba-macros-protect-userinterfaceonly/).

Comment: Yup... That was what I was looking for. Thank you verey much.